# How to use regex to delete some files in a directory in swift 3

Tags: ios, regex, swift

I need to delete all the files in a document directory which match with the pattern :

myproject-(anything).sqlite-(anything)

for now, I'm doing it, one by one:

```
let oldSqlitePath : NSString = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("myproject-\(lastAppVersion!).sqlite") as NSString
let oldSqliteWalPath : NSString = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("myproject-\(lastAppVersion!).sqlite-wal") as NSString
let oldSqliteShmPath : NSString = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("myproject-\(lastAppVersion!).sqlite-shm") as NSString

 do {
    // delete the old SQLite file
    try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: oldSqlitePath as String)
 } catch _ {
 }
 do {
    try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: oldSqliteWalPath as String)
 } catch _ {
 }
 do {
    try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: oldSqliteShmPath as String)
 } catch _ {
 }
```

I would like to use a regex.

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: I don't find a correct way to define the string myproject-(anything).sqlite-(anything) using regex.

Comment: `myproject-[^.]*\.sqlite-.*` isn't perfect but should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think regex makes sense here if you just have always just 4 items to remove. I use something like this.

```
extension URL {

    public var sqliteFileURLs: [URL] {

        let wal: String = "\(path)-wal"
        let journal: String = "\(path)-journal"
        let shm: String = "\(path)-shm"

        let filesNames: [String] = [path, wal, shm, journal]

        return filesNames
            .filter { FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: $0) }
            .map { (path: String) -> URL in URL(fileURLWithPath: path) }
    }
}
```

And then you can do `path.sqliteFileURLs.map { FileManager.default.removeItem(at: $0 }`

In case you really want to use a regex, this is it: `myproject\-.+?\.sqlite\-.+`

Comment: Thanks but I gave just an example. I have more than 3 items :)

Comment: Responded with a regex to use also